# Strange Networking Issue: Ports 80 and 433 Unreachable from Outside, Docker

Tags: networking, iptables, docker, docker-compose, ufw

I'm encountering a perplexing networking issue that has me scratching my head. Here's the situation: I'm unable to access ports 80 and 433 from the outside, but I can forward any other port within Docker, and it works flawlessly! I've set up UFW and also have K3s installed, but the bulk of my services run using Docker Compose.

To investigate further, I launched a Nginx test container, and things took an even weirder turn.

I can reach this test container using its internal Docker IP, but even a simple `curl -I 127.0.0.1` results in a 404 error:

```bash
-> # curl -I 127.0.0.1

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Wed, 20 Sep 2023 00:39:26 GMT
Content-Length: 19
```

The plot thickens when I discover that I can access it from another internal IP (a VPN network):

```bash
-> # curl -I 192.168.10.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.25.2
Date: Wed, 20 Sep 2023 00:41:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 615
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Aug 2023 17:03:04 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "64dbafc8-267"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

But here's the kicker: When I stop the container, you'd expect to see an error like this:

```bash
-> # curl -I 127.0.0.1

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

However, no, I'm greeted with the same persistent 404 error!

---

**UPDATE:** Adding to the mystery, when I turn off the Docker container, attempting to access `192.168.10.1` also results in a 404 error:

```bash
-> # curl -I 192.168.10.1

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Wed, 20 Sep 2023 00:51:49 GMT
Content-Length: 19
```

I'm completely stumped and have no idea where the issue is originating from. To make things even more confounding, I can repeat this experiment with port 81, and everything works as expected. If anyone has any insights or suggestions on how to debug this, I'd greatly appreciate your help!

---

Here some further outputs:

```bash
-> # lsof -i:80

COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 9815 root    4u  IPv4  54638      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
docker-pr 9823 root    4u  IPv6  48079      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

```bash
-> # docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                               NAMES
975e74d4bdfd   nginx:latest          "/docker-entrypoint.…"   29 minutes ago   Up 29 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp   nginx_test_nginx-test_1
```

```bash
-> # ufw status

Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
Anywhere                   ALLOW       192.168.178.0/24
81/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
81/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)


Anywhere on eth0           ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on wghub
Anywhere on wghub          ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on wghub
Anywhere (v6) on eth0      ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6) on wghub
Anywhere (v6) on wghub     ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6) on wghub
```

```bash
-> # netstat -ltnp

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10010         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1374/containerd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      631/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9815/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      610/systemd-resolve
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      631/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      9823/docker-proxy
```

```bash
-> # cat /etc/default/docker

DOCKER_OPTS="--iptables=false"
```

---

**UPDATE:** This is my test configuration:

`docker-compose.yml`

```bash
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-test:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Comment: So, the nginx in the container answers. The nginx config is most probably wrong. Check the `server_name` directives.

Comment: Added the compose file for the test. I don't think it's nginx related. If I try for example `image: "containous/whoami"` there is the same result.